# To Show $f(A,B)=B^{T}A^{-1}B$ is K-convex on $\mathbb{S}_{++}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Here, $K = \mathbb{S}_+^n$, a set collecting all PSD matrix. And $\mathbb{S}_{++}^n$ is a set colleting all PD matrix.

I've tried to start from $f(X) = X^{-1}$ is also K-convex on $\mathbb{S}_{++}^n$.
And applying the property of norm formed by inner product. However, I can't derive the desired K-convexity inequality, i.e. $z^Tf(\theta(A,B)+(1-\theta)(X,Y))z \leq z^T(\theta f(A,B)+(1-\theta)f(X,Y))z$.

And I've tried second-order condition on $g(t) = f((A,B)+t(X,Y))$. There comes out too much term; as a result, I can't show $g''(t)\geq 0$

Now I'm tring to prove this question from $\textbf{epi}_K f$ and show $\textbf{epi}_K f$ is intersection of closed halfspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schur complement:
Consider a mtrxi $X \in \mathbb{S}^n_+$ partitioned as
$\begin{bmatrix} 
A & B\\
B^T & C
\end{bmatrix}$
where $A \in \mathbb{S}^k_+$. If $\det(A)\neq 0$, the matrix $S = C-B^TA^{-1}B$ is called the ''Schur complement'' of $A$ in $X$.

And we have Theorem: If $A$ is PD, then $X$ is PSD iff $S$ is PSD.

Consider the ${\bf{epi}}_K\;f = \{(A,B,t):\; (A,B) \in \mbox{dom},   f,\; t \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}, \;z^T(t - B^T A^{-1}B)z \geq 0 \} = \{(A,B,t):\; \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & t  \end{bmatrix} \mbox{is PSD}, A\;\mbox{is PD}\}$

by applying the Theorem of Schur complement.

As a result, ${\bf epi}_K f $ is convex, which implies f is K-convex.

Comment: Interesting proof.  Shouldn't the inequality defining the epigraph should be $t \geq z^TB^T A^{-1} B z$ instead of $tz^Tz \geq z^TB^T A^{-1} B z$ ?

Comment: Since $f$ is K-convex, this is not normal epigraph, but epigraph with general inequality (with $K$, here $K$ is $\mathbb{S}^n_+$). As a result, the definition is slightly different from epigraph.

Answer (score 0):

By choosing $B,Y$, the inequality wlog becomes:
$(\theta u + (1-\theta)v)^T (\theta A+ (1-\theta)X)^{-1} (\theta u + (1-\theta)v) \leq \theta u^TA^{-1} u + (1-\theta) v^TX^{-1} v$
Special case: $AX=XA$: 
If $AX=XA$ then $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable and the problem reduces to $A,X$ being diagonal matrices. The inequality becomes:
$(\theta u_i + (1-\theta)v_i)^2 \frac{1}{\theta a_{ii} + (1-\theta)x_{ii}} \leq \theta u_i^2 \frac{1}{a_{ii}} + (1-\theta) v_i^2 \frac{1}{x_{ii}}.$
This follows from convexity of $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{y}$ on $\{(x,y): y>0\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I check your negative result multiple times. I think you're right. On the other hand, this problem is wrong since the prof wants us to prove not "prove or give a counter example".

Comment: Sure. But check if there are any more constraints given by your prof in this problem within which you need to prove.

Comment: Hello, I found that there is a problem in your answer. You wrote $\theta a_{11} + (1-\theta)x_{11}$ which  is not correct. Since $(A+X)^{-1} \neq A^{-1}+X^{-1}$

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Assume $A = diag(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$, $B = diag(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n)$. $(A+B) = diag(a_1+b_1,\dots,a_n+b_n)$. So $(A+B)^{-1} = diag(\frac{1}{a_1+b_1},\dots,\frac{1}{a_n+b_n})$ which is not equal to $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer. Sorry about that. Just now seeing.

Comment: Now the identity seems to be true. Good catch. I will think.

Comment: In this case, I check that $x_{11}$ only appearing in the right doesn't matter. It won't violate the inequality.

Comment: Are u still interested in proving this or this is proved in your class already by your prof ?

Comment: Prof doesn't provide the answer. And there is a new question that needs this result to prove or using the same approach. New question is to prove $f(A,B) = \mbox{Tr}(B^TA^{-1}B)$ is convex on $\mathbb{S}^m_{++} \times \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$

Comment: I figure out how to prove this, I'll type in the following later.

Comment: I saw your answer. Nice solution. Changed my answer to a proof for special case. Interesting problem. Thanks